# How to sending email in C# without entering password?

Tags: c#

How do you send an email without entering a password?

I made this:

```
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(emailtxt.Text.Trim());
mail.To.Add("myadressemail@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "test";
mail.Body = "test";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
client.Send(mail);
```

Is it possible to send an email to Gmail without an authorization?
If not, are there any better alternatives?

Less secure apps are off.

Comment: Send email **to** gmail? For sure, you just need to send the email **from** a server that allows you to send emails. If, on the other hand, you want to send emails *using* gmail then you absolutely need to authenticate with their server.

Comment: Gmail is going to require some form of authentication, whether you're sending emails via SMTP or using their dedicated API's that they provide. Otherwise, anybody could impersonate anyone, and Gmail would cease to be useful. What's the purpose of this email? Some sort of notification?

Comment: @mason Its a contact form. User can send email to us with some issues or question.

Comment: Note that email has evolved and most servers these days require the sending server to have been configured to identify who is sending the emails, as well as identify the server that is sending the emails. This is to make it harder to send spam masquerading as being from any random person. You absolutely should not create a program that require the smtp server you send through to accept anonymous requests, as this might flag the emails as spam, deserved or not.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So what i should do. I cant force user to enter user's password. Or i can?

Comment: You *could*, but that's not recommended. Instead create a dedicated email account for your app to send the email from, like "noreply@example.com" or "notifications@example.com" and then send the email *from* that account.

Comment: Why not just make the form submit the data to your own backend that can then use your own smtp server for sending the email?

Comment: Okay but when user send email TO US. I want to see his email address because for example i will want send him back something.

Comment: So, ask the user to include the email while filling out the form. You can then append it to the body or subject of the email, or use the Reply-To header.

Comment: @mason thats sound good.

Comment: @mason and now is posible to hide in ` mail.To.Add("myadressemail@gmail.com")` address email? so that it cannot be seen from the code level for users

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by hiding that. Are you talking about obfuscating your code? What type of app is this? ASP.NET? Win Forms? WPF?

Comment: @mason Yes, obfuscating. WinForm (.NET/C#)

Comment: A determined user will always be able to reverse engineer an obfuscated app. The only sure way of preventing them from obtaining something is to not give it to them in the first place. Therefore, you either need to change your email behavior to not rely on having credentials, by having it launch the user's default email program pre-populated with your company's address in the "To" line, or to have the Win Forms app communicate over the network to an endpoint your control (such as an HTTP API you've hosted) and have that API be responsible for sending the email.

Comment: You're pretty much asking how to do email forgery; as other have mentioned the "good practice" on contact forms is to have your own, internal, dedicated email address AND ask the user/customer for their email address as part of the contact form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to send an email to Gmail without an authorization?

No

> If not, are there any better alternatives?

As Mason mentions in the comments, the main alternatives are:

1. Use a mailto-link to open the users default email program to send the message. This will obviously reveal the email address, but presumably this would happen anyway if you reply to their email.
2. Setup a simple web-api that receives messages from your application and forwards them to an internal smtp server, or some other system to handle messages. If you want to reply to the user using email you would need to ask him/her for their email address. If you want to ensure the email is correct you could send an automated verification email to the address, and only forward the message once the address has been verified.

There is no real way getting around the need for authentication on the modern internet. The modern way of dealing with this in automated systems would typically be with certificates and API-keys, but email is a quite old protocol with more limited authentication methods.